# What is the geometric difference between the eigenvectors and eigenspace of a 3x3 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand the geometric difference between a transformations:

- "Eigenvectors"
- "Eigenspace"
- "Maximal set of nonzero orthogonal eigenvectors"

Let's say we have this symmetric 3x3 matrix:
$$B_1 =\begin{bmatrix}
11 & -8 & 4 \\
-8 & -1 & -2 \\
4 & -2 & -4  
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It has the following eigenvalues: $\lambda_1 = -5, \lambda_2 = 16$.

Now using $\lambda_2$, I found one eigenvector, $v_1 = (4,-2,1)$ with this eigenvalue. From what I understand, **an eigenvector is a vector that stays in the same span (stretches/squished by a scalar) following a transformation**. Therefore, the span of this eigenvector is:

$$ span(v_1) = \{a\begin{bmatrix}
4\\
-2 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix},  a\in\mathbb R \}$$

**Question 1:** Is this span the same as the eigenspace?

Now using $\lambda_1$, I end up getting an eigenvector, $u_1$, that seems to be a linear combination of two other vectors:

$$u_1 = b*m + c*n  = b\begin{bmatrix}
0.5\\
1\\
0 
\end{bmatrix} + c\begin{bmatrix}
-0.25\\
0 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0.25\\
1\\
1 
\end{bmatrix}, b = 1, c= 1$$

This is where I get really confused.

**Question 2:** Are $u_1$, $m$, and $n$ all eigenvectors that stay on their respective lines after a transformation?

**Question 3:** Do $m$ and $n$ form the basis vectors that span a plane of vectors (one of which is $u_1$)? Does this mean the plane is stretched or squished by the eigenvalue? Is this plane also an "eigenspace"?

**Question 4:** What is the "maximal set of orthogonal eigenvectors"? Is that simply the $span(v_1)$ + $span(m,n)$?

Comment: You're mostly thinking about it the right way. The answers to questions 2 and 3 are yes yes yes yes. $\lambda_1$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity 2, so the corresponding eigenspace is 2-dimensional. We don't call a proper subspace of an eigenspace an eigenspace, though, so although $m$ is an eigenvector, $\operatorname{span}(m)$ is not an eigenspace. But $\operatorname{span}(v_1)$ is. For question 4 you want a set of vectors that are all orthogonal to each other, so it'll have just three elements.

Comment: Ok, so $v_1$ is already orthogonal to $m$ and $n$, but $m$ and $n$ are not orthogonal to each other. So I need to find another vector orthogonal to either $m$ or $n$ that is in their plane.

Answer (score 1):

First let's note that any non-zero vector of the form
$$ b\begin{bmatrix}
0.5\\
1\\
0 
\end{bmatrix} + c\begin{bmatrix}
-0.25\\
0 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix} $$
is an eigenvector for this value.

Q1. Yes. The eigenspace is spanned by all the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue. In this case is just the span of this eigenvector.

Q2 and Q3. Yes this is correct.

Q4. You just need an eigenvector corresponding to $16$ and two orthogonal vectors from the eigenspace for eigenvalue $-5$.

Comment: Ok so the orthogonal vectors from the eigenspace for eigenvalue −5 have to be orthogonal to each other?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Choose any one (e.g with b=1,c=0) and then find an  eigenvector with zero dot product with the first vector.